# What is the difference between Cocoa Touch Framework and pre-Xcode6 framework

Tags: frameworks, ios8

In Xcode 6 and iOS 8, Apple allows us to create "Cocoa Touch framework" using a built-in template in Xcode.

But before Xcode 6, we still can build our own framework using Aggregate and some script.

They also says that Framework is not available in iOS 7 and below.

> If you link to an embedded framework from your containing app, you can still deploy it to versions of iOS older than 8.0, even though embedded frameworks are not available in those versions.
>   Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3

So what is the difference between pre-Xcode 6 framework and Xcode 6 framework?
And will my customized pre-Xcode 6 framework stop working when I move to Xcode 6?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the new framework is linked dynamically at runtime, while the pre one is linked statically into your app binary.

and dynamic linking is disabled on ios7 and prior versions